# is there any way we can get positioned ancestor for an absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

How do we know the nearest positioned parent element to an absolute element?
any js scripts or plugins available to play around

Comment: [DUPLICATED] You can Find your answer here: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I would start playing with something like this:

```
function getPositionAnchor(startFromElm) {
  var positionAnchor = null;
  var validAnchors = ['relative','absolute','fixed'];
  var elm = startFromElm.parentElement;    
  do {
    if (validAnchors.indexOf(getComputedStyle(elm)['position']) !== -1
        || elm.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'html') {
      positionAnchor = elm;
    } else {
      elm = elm.parentElement;  
    }
  } while (!positionAnchor)
  return positionAnchor;
}
```